# ODP.NET Integrated Security Invalid Connection String Argument

Tags: .net, oracle, connection-string, odp.net, integrated-security

What am I missing?

```
<add name="test" 
    connectionString="Data Source=TEST_ORACLE;Integrated Security=Yes;" />

[ArgumentException: 'Integrated Security' is an invalid connection string attribute]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.ParseConnectionString() +2707
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +533
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +210
```

ODP.NET: Oracle.DataAccess - 2.102.2.20 (I am using a bindingRedirect to this version.)

If I take out Integrated Security and declare User ID and password then it functions correctly. So, I know there is nothing wrong with ODP.NET.

Comment: Not sure if it matters on Oracle, but http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p12 states it should be `Data Source=TEST_ORACLE;Integrated Security=SSPI;`.

Comment: Made that change... same error.

Comment: It should work, but I don't have an Oracle around to test on ... Which ODP version is this ?

Comment: I added the Oracle.DataAccess version at the bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that ODP has the Integrated Security Attribute:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm#i1006259

but this site (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/code-154692.html)
 states

> To migrate to ODP.NET, remove these
>   attributes if they are part of the
>   Microsoft OracleClient connection
>   string.
>
> ```
> * Integrated Security -- Set " User Id=/" in the ODP.NET connection
> ```
>
> string for the equivalent operating
>   system authentication.

which is the same that these guys go through: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=583813&tstart=405

So use **User Id=/** and see if that works

also make sure to have your sqlnet.ora  have "SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)"

Comment: I struggled with this before realising that sqlnet.ora isn't automatically discovered by ODP. Rather than making it available to the code, you can add `OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAuthenticationServices = "nts";`