# ASP.NET Oracle ODP.NET Integrated Security Slowness

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-string, odp.net, integrated-security

The following results in successful sub-second page loads.

```
<add name="test" 
    connectionString="Data Source=TEST_ORACLE;User Id=user;Password=password;" />
```

The following subtle change to use the app pool's custom identity results in successful page loads that are 20+ times slower.

```
<add name="test" 
    connectionString="Data Source=TEST_ORACLE;User Id=/;" />
```

It appears that I at least got the trusted connection to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Integrated Security=SSPI;` instead of `User Id=/;`

Does your app pool identity have network logon rights?

Comment: Have you tested this with ODP.NET?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950897/odp-net-integrated-security-invalid-connection-string-argument

Comment: If my app pool identity didn't have logon rights.. I'd be getting errors instead of successful, but slow, page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The connections strings that I use look like

```
<add 
    name="myOracleConnection" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE))); User Id=MyUser; Password=MyPassword;" 
    providerName="system.data.oracleclient"/>
```

I.e. I do not rely on these external configuration files (were they named `.ora`? I forgot it).

Maybe you can lower dependencies and side-effects if you also try to make your connection string self-containing with *everything* included?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be my issue.

Comment: It appears any side effects are introduced with Integrated Security "User Id=/", not with the .ora entries.